# Bottom Navigation showing in other fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I will be glad to finally get a help for this. I have a single activity application. One of the fragments is also a nav_host(say nav_host2) to other fragments for its bottom navigation.

I want to exit from the from fragment in nav_host two to nav_host1 using deep-linking but notice that the bottom navigation on nav_host2 show on nav_host1 which I do not want as seen in the diagram below.

[image: Sign-in fragment in nav_host1]

How can I exit the nav_host2 without having the bottom navigation show even-though it is null

Answer (score 0):

use `addOnDestinationChangedListener` and hide and show `bottomNavigation` with respect to destinationId

```
private val AUTH_NAV_GRAPH = arrayOf(
    R.id.destination_splash,
    R.id.destination_login,
    R.id.destination_register,
    R.id.destination_forgetpassword
)



val navController = findNavController(this,R.id.nav_host_fragment)// this maybe change
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { controller, destination, arguments ->
   if(destination.id in AUTH_NAV_GRAPH) {
       bottomNavigation?.visibility=View.GONE

   } else {
       bottomNavigation?.visibility=View.VISIBLE
   }
}
```

where `AUTH_NAV_GRAPH` are like fragments with no `bottomNavigation`